# Box Developer Account JWT Auth Related query

Tags: python, django, jwt, box

I am using BoxSDK for python. There I am using JWT authentication. I have created an app on Developer account for testing which uses authentication as OAuth 2.0 with JSON Web Tokens (Server Authentication).

After creating this TestApp in developer account I am using it in some APIs to do some basic operations in Box. I also got an Service Account ID. related to my test app.

All good till here.

But I am facing issue when I am uploading a folder in my box account through browser and then try accessing that folder contents via Box API, its not accessible.

The same is accessible when I am adding the service account ID as a collaborator in that folder.

So I want to know if there is any option using which I dont need to do the above part i.e. adding service account ID as a collaborator in every folder that I want to access through API. Please suggest.

Is this behavior only for test account? If I take Enterprise edition of Box, will this issue be solved?

I need that whatever folder I upload in Box through website, it should be accessible vis API where I am using JWT authentication.

Many thanks for your help.

Tried as per tutorials. Need to access all folder without adding Service account ID as collaborator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, check you app configurations in your dev console > your app > configurations tab and make sure:

1. Under App Access Level you have App+Enterprise Access
2. Under Advanced features, select Make API calls using the as-user header
3. Save changes
4. Under Authorization tab, re-authorize your app if needed.

Now you can try this piece of code:

```
"""quick demo to list items in folder while impersonating a user"""
from boxsdk import JWTAuth, Client


def main():
    """main function"""
    auth = JWTAuth.from_settings_file('./.jwt.config.json')
    auth.authenticate_instance()
    client = Client(auth)

    me = client.user().get()
    print(f"Service account user: {me.id}:{me.name}")

    user_id_to_impersonate = '18622116055'
    folder_of_user_to_impersonate = '0'

    user_to_impersonate = client.user(user_id=user_id_to_impersonate).get()
    # the .get() is just to be able to print the impersonated user
    print(f"User to impersonate: {user_to_impersonate.id}:{user_to_impersonate.name}")

    user_client = client.as_user(user_to_impersonate)
    items = user_client.folder(folder_id=folder_of_user_to_impersonate).get_items()

    print(f"Items in folder:{items}")
    # we need a loop to actually get the items info
    for item in items:
        print(f"Item: {item.type}\t{item.id}\t{item.name}")
```

Resulting in:

```
Service account user: 20344589936:UI-Elements-Sample
User to impersonate: 18622116055:Rui Barbosa

Item: folder    172759373899    Barduino User Folder
Item: folder    172599089223    Bookings
Item: folder    162833533610    Box Reports
Item: folder    163422716106    Box UI Elements Demo
Item: folder    191176042455    Bulk Upload
Item: folder    189803765719    ClassificationService
```